# C# class ? in property (what does it mean?)

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm studying for my MCPD and this example class is on shown in the ADO.net Entity Framework example. I haven't encounter ? in the property such as OrderDate and EmployeeID Can someone please explain to me what it does or mean?

```
public class Order
{
 public int OrderID { get; set; }

 public string CustomerID { get; set; }
 public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
 public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime? RequiredDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime? ShippedDate { get; set; }
 public int? ShipVia { get; set; }
 public decimal? Freight { get; set; }
 public string ShipName { get; set; }
 public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
 public string ShipCity { get; set; }
 public string ShipRegion { get; set; }
 public string ShipPostalCode { get; set; }
 public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
 public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The type `X?` is short-hand for the type [`Nullable<X>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), where `X` is value-type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's short for the type [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) where `T` is the type that precedes the `?`. Thus

```
public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
```

is equivalent to

```
public Nullable<int> EmployeeID { get; set; }
```

Effectively, a nullable type allows you to assign `null` to value types. These types are very special as various operators and methods on the corresponding non-nullable type are "lifted" to the nullable type.

Note that `T` must be a non-nullable value type. Also, it's a common misconception that `Nullable<T>` is a reference type. It is a value type, albeit a rather special one (it gets help from the compiler to be so special). For example, boxing and unboxing operations are treated very specially (the underlying value is boxed, unless it is `null` in which case the boxed instance of `object` is the `null` reference; if `null` is unboxed to an instance of a nullable type, it is unboxed to the value where `HasValue` is `false`).

Answer (score 4):

It means its nullable. A nullable value can contain a value or it can be null, like this:

```
int? myVar = 4;

myVar = null //myVar is now null. This would be illegal is myVar wasn't nullable

myVar = 17 // myVar now contains 17
```

Answer (score 3):

It means the variable is nullable.

Comment: In the example given, there are no variables, only properties with a type of `Nullable<T>` for various `T`.

Comment: Yes, but what does it mean when a variable (or property) is 
"nullable"? Where can more information be found? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: I chose variable so that I wasn't specifically limiting it to properties.  I think the point is clear enough.

Comment: @Mystere Man: Properties are not special cases of variables, so you haven't included them by saying "variables." Wrong points are still wrong.

Comment: @pst - The advantage of a nullable variable is that you can set it to null when you otherwise would not be able to (it only makes sense to make value types nullable).  There is no disadvantage, other than it be set to null when you might not want to.

Comment: @Jason - a "variable" means something that can change.  A property is very much a variable.  It isn't, necessarily, a field or global memory location.. I think this is just a matter of semantics.

Comment: 1. That is not what "variable" means. 2. If that were the correct definition of "variable", then not all properties would be variables. 3. It is a matter of semantics; there are correct and incorrect uses of words and you are using "variable" incorrectly.

Comment: @Jason - From the dictionary http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/variable Mathematics, Computers. a. a quantity or function that may assume any given value or set of values. b. a symbol that represents this. A property very much fits the definition of a variable.  It's just not a local, global, or field.

Comment: @Mystere Man: That definition is wrong insofar as C# is concerned. In C#, a variable is defined as a storage location whose contents can vary. Properties are methods that have a special syntax that makes them appear as if they are fields but they are emphatically not storage locations (although they might be "backed" by a storage location). Also, non-technical dictionaries are generally not the best source for the meanings of technical terms.

Comment: @Mystere Man: Specifically, the language specification is the ultimate source to settle arguments such as this. I note the following from 1.6.7.2: "However, unlike fields, properties do not denote storage locations." The first sentence of chapter 5. (Variables) is "Variables represent storage locations." Section 5.1 states "C# defines seven categories of variables: static variables, instance variables, array elements, value parameters, reference parameters, output parameters, and local variables." Note the absence of "properties." You might find this chapter to be illuminating reading.

Comment: @Jason - It's a mathematical term.  I see that the C# lanaguage designers have redefined its meaning, however I still believe the term is valid casually, given it's mathematical history.  Mathematically, a function can be a variable.  And properties do imply storage backing (but do not require it).  In all honesty, given that ref and out parameters are considered variables, as well as value parameters (like those passed via properties), I think the term should apply.

Comment: @Mystere Man: It's a technical term. Some technical terms have meanings that depend on context. You can't use a given contextual meaning of such a term in a context in which it wasn't meant to be used. Properties do not imply storage backing. Your thought that the term should apply is wrong. The term "variable" has a very specific meaning in C# and you can not bend it as you see fit without causing confusion.

Comment: @Mystere Man: Your understanding of "value parameters" is confused if you think they being storage locations implies that properties should be considered storage locations as well. If `void M(int value)` is a method with value parameter `value` and it is invoked via `M(a.PropertyNamedFoo)` then the value of `a.PropertyNamedFoo` is copied into the value parameter `value`. It is not, Not, NOT an alias for `a.PropertyNamedFoo`, whether or not `a.PropertyNamedFoo` is a value type or a reference type.

Comment: @Mystere Man: One last point: note that this is never legal `void M(ref int value) { }`. Then: `M(ref a.PropertyNamedFoo)`. This is never legal because a `ref` parameter in `M` is an alias for the storage location as the variable given as the argument in the method invocation. Such an argument has to be a variable (it has to be a storage location). Properties are not variables, and therefore they are not legitimate `ref` arguments (similarly for `out`).

Comment: @Jason - For a guy that's so pedantic, you certainly do read a lot into things.  I did not say that because value parameters are variables then that means that Properties are.  Not everyone is a pedant, and in fact use terms casually, even if they're not exact.  A variable has a pre-existing meaning that nearly everyone is familiar with, except you apparently.  Just because the C# Language authors chose to define the term more narrowly in the specificaion doesn't mean you can't use the term casually to mean more.

Comment: @Jason You're being an idiot purely for the sake of being an idiot. Stop.

Comment: @Mystere Man: Look, you're wrong. Attacking the man instead of the content doesn't make you less wrong.

Comment: @Rob: Either attack the content or move on.

Comment: @Jason You're pointing out something so _trivial_ just so you can feel good about saying someone else is wrong. The fact of the matter is, properties and variables are _so_ similar that to be honest, it makes no difference in this case.

Comment: @Rob: I have no idea what makes you think you have insight into my motives (you're wrong). The fact of the matter is, just because properties use field-like syntax does not make them "so" similar to fields to be considered variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

[ValueType]? is shorthand for the Nullable class.

It will accept a null assignment (which value types can't).
When you're ready to access the value, you can check `myNullable == null` or `myNullable.HasValue` and the actual valueType (int, DateTime, whatever) will be in `myNullable.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

It just makes the value nullable.  Which means you can assign "null" to the property.  Without the "?" You wouldn't be able to.

Answer (score 0):

nullable, when you use the database, you can set column as int null
so in the c# int is not null,because int is the value type. so in c# support the int?